# Jenkins job specify sudo password for Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, centos7

```
    Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace /opt/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/tomcat installation
    [tomcat installation] $ sshpass ******** /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /opt/ansible_scripts/tomcat-install.yaml -f 5 -u root -k -e =
    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
    the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

    PLAY [Installing tomcat] *******************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

    FATAL: command execution failed
    hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:232)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Can you give more detail?

Comment: https://code-maven.com/enable-ansible-passwordless-sudo Follow the steps here - which solution you choose is up to you.

Comment: Issue is resolved, I was running jenkins as tomcat user as jenkins was running on tomcat. I've uninstalled and run jenkins as standalone with root and I don't see sudo password exception.

Thanks for your reply @MichaelNiemand

Comment: Thanks for your the article @bobdylan